# PayPal Rest API SDK: How to add the SOLUTIONTYPE option (or equivalent)

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I would like my PayPal express checkout integration, which uses the PHP Rest API SDK, to show the option 'pay using a debet or credit card' but that option is currently not showing.

'PayPal account optional' is on in the account settings, so that's not the problem.

I have figured out that for the classic API I would need to add the option

> 'SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole'

to the SetExpressCheckout call but the Rest API docs make no mention of this option and a code search through the SDK doesn't turn up any hits.

Does anyone know how to enable this option through the Rest API/Rest API PHP SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `SOLUTIONTYPE` is not supported in REST API as of now.
List of variables available in [Web Experience](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-experience-overview/)

Comment: What I don't understand is that PayPal pushes the use of the REST API while it lacks basic options like this... This forces me to redo my work using the classic API :(

Comment: See the [PayPal Github issue](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/331)